# How can I replace a Perl hash key?

Tags: perl, hash, replace

Let us say if I have a hash like this:

```
$data = {
    'key1' => {
                'key2' => 'value1'
              },
    'key3' => {
                'key4' => {
                            'key5' => 'value2'
                          }
              },
};
```

Now, how can I replace the the key 'key5' with some other key name, say 'key6'?

I know how to loop through the hash and dump the values, but I don't know how to replace keys or values in place.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `delete` operator returns the value being deleted. So this

```
$data->{key3}{key4}{key6} = delete $data->{key3}{key4}{key5}
```

will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for that. I actually didn't even know that it was possible to do it that way

Comment: The syntax highlighting seems off. Perhaps use `lang-none`?

Answer (score 9):

You can't replace it, but you can make a new key easily, and then [`delete()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) the old one:

```
$data->{key3}{key4}{key6} = $data->{key3}{key4}{key5};
delete $data->{key3}{key4}{key5};
```

Of course, you could make a fairly simple subroutine to do this. However, my first approach was wrong, and you would need to make a more complex approach that passes in the data structure to modify and the element to be modified, and given that you want elements several levels deep this may be difficult. Though if you don't mind a little clutter:

```
sub hash_replace (\%$$) {
  $_[0]->{$_[2]} = delete $_[0]->{$_[1]}; # thanks mobrule!
}
```

Then call it:

```
hash_replace %{$data->{key3}{key4}}, "key5", "key6";
```

Or the cool way (How better to say that we're transforming "key5" into "key6" ?):

```
hash_replace %{$data->{key3}{key4}}, key5 => "key6";
```

(Tested and works)

Comment: This is great, thanks for your help. This example is really good for me to understand how to approach this.

Comment: The syntax highlighting seems off. Perhaps use `lang-none`?

Answer (score 0):

This 'works', but it is very hard-coded.

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $data = {
    'key1' => {
        'key2' => 'value1'
    },
    'key3' => {
        'key4' => {
            'key5' => 'value2'
        }
    },
};

print "$data->{key3}->{key4}->{key5}\n";

my $save = $data->{key3}->{key4}->{key5};
delete $data->{key3}->{key4}->{key5};
$data->{key3}->{key4}->{key6} = $save;

print "$data->{key3}->{key4}->{key6}\n";
```

You can eliminate the '->' operators between the hash subscripts, but not the one after '$data' - as in [Chris Lutz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490356/how-can-i-replace-a-perl-hash-key/1490369#1490369).

Comment: I always preferred to use the fewest number of `->` that I could get away with, but I can see how it starts to get hairy quickly.