# How to restructure hash of hashes of hashes?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash of hash of hash as

```
hash_1 =>{
           hash_2=>{
               a1 => {           
                      1 => m,
                      2 => x,
                      3 => n
                     },
               a2 =>  {
                      1 => a,
                      2 => x,
                      3 => b
                      },
                a3 =>  {
                      1 => c,
                      2 => y,
                      3 => d
                      },
                a4 =>  {
                      1 => i,
                      2 => y,
                      3 => j
                      },
             },
         };
```

Now I want to delete the key "hash_2" and and add new keys in place of "hash_2" which depends on the value of the key "2" inside each hashes a1, a2, a3... So, like here we have two different values for the key "2" : x and y. So I want this values to be in place of the key of the first hash "hash_2" and create a new hash map altogether.
So end result should be :

```
  hash_1 =>{
           x=>{
               a1 => {           
                      1 => m,
                      2 => x,
                      3 => n
                     },
               a2 =>  {
                      1 => a,
                      2 => x,
                      3 => b
                      },
              },
            y => {
                a3 =>  {
                      1 => c,
                      2 => y,
                      3 => d
                      },
                a4 =>  {
                      1 => i,
                      2 => y,
                      3 => j
                      },
             },
         };
```

I checked [How to replace a Perl hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490356/how-to-replace-a-perl-hash-key) but could not get how to make a value of a key as a key.
I tried deleting the hash_2 but was not successful(using the delete keyword).
Thanks.

Comment: One, but not nice way is to save the key1 as tmp. Then delete the key from the hash. At in the ende create an new key from the tmp. Maybe so: my $tmp = $hash_name->{key1}; delete $hash_name->{key1}; $hash_name->{x} = $tmp.

Comment: But I don't want key1 at all. I want the value of the key in the 3rd hash as the new key1.

Comment: This is a good time to ask yourself how you ended up with this data structure instead of the data structure you wanted, and step back and find a way to end up with the data structure you wanted rather than the data structure you ended up with.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my $hash_1 = {
  hash_2 => {
    a1 => { 1 => "m", 2 => "x", 3 => "n" },
    a2 => { 1 => "a", 2 => "x", 3 => "b" },
    a3 => { 1 => "c", 2 => "y", 3 => "d" },
    a4 => { 1 => "i", 2 => "y", 3 => "j" },
  }
};

{
    my $data = delete $hash_1->{hash_2};

    for my $key ( keys %$data ) {
        my $item = $data->{$key};
        $hash_1->{ $item->{2} }{ $key } = $item;
    }
}

dd $hash_1;
```

#### output

```
{
  x => {
         a1 => { 1 => "m", 2 => "x", 3 => "n" },
         a2 => { 1 => "a", 2 => "x", 3 => "b" },
       },
  y => {
         a3 => { 1 => "c", 2 => "y", 3 => "d" },
         a4 => { 1 => "i", 2 => "y", 3 => "j" },
       },
}
```